# Unable to cast transparent proxy to type from AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, appdomain

I'm trying to create an object in an appdomain:

```
var type = typeof (CompiledTemplate);
var obj = (CompiledTemplate) domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (
    type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
```

However, I always get the following error:

*Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Mono.TextTemplating.CompiledTemplate'.*

I'm running on .NET 4.0, not Mono, despite what the namespace might suggest :)

As far as I know, this error happens when .NET thinks that the Type & Assembly do not exactly match in the two domains. However, when debugging, the FullName and Location are identical. Only the Assembly.Codebase property differs - in the child AppDomain its extension is uppercased to "DLL" for some reason.

I've tried adding an AssemblyResolve handler to the AppDomain, which uses Assembly.LoadFrom to load the filename explicitly, but the CodeBase's extension still gets uppercased. Since the original assembly was also loaded with Assembly.LoadFrom (via Mono.Addins), the difference between the CodeBase values seems very strange.

Any suggestions for fixing or working around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you be running into an issue with assembly load contexts?
(e.g. see [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2007/03/06/Assembly-Load-Contexts-Subtleties.aspx))
You have a type that's clearly in the load context (because you're using `typeof(CompiledTemplate)`), but you're saying that the type in the secondary AD is loaded into the load-from context...

Did you check with [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to determine exactly what assemblies are being loaded? The fuslog trace will also tell you if the assemblies are being loaded into different contexts.

Comment: The problem does seem to be load contexts. It *attempts* to load filenames into the load context, based the assemblyname -  fusion log indicates that the loader is attempting to load {ApplicationBase}\{AssemblyName}.DLL - i.e. that's where the uppercase "DLL" is coming from. How I just need to figure out why it was ignoring the assembly I already loaded into the LoadFrom context...

Comment: Assemblies loaded into the LF context are invisible as far as assemblies in the L context are concerned.

Comment: I got it working with an AssemblyResolve handler that resolved everything after the first assembly, instead of a handler that just resolved specific assemblies.

Comment: This has caused me more aggravation than anything else when dealing with AppDomains.  It is completely not clear what is going on.  And its even worse because you can't control contexts when using CreateInstance/AndUnwrap.  I wish MS would create a type (extending MBRO) that could be used in lieu of AppDomain.CreateInstace that offers more control over loading assemblies and instantiating types.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword instead of casting it to a specific type:

```
var type = typeof (CompiledTemplate);
dynamic obj = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (
    type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
```

That might at least give you a workaround to the problem.  Of course, the potential drawbacks will be not having compile time checking and/or slower performance.  However, these might be negligible trade-offs depending on your situation.

Comment: We aren't able to upgrade our codebase to .NET 4 at this time, unfortunately. I'd also prefer not to bloat the process by having two copies of the same assembly loaded...

Answer (score 1):

A second copy of the assembly is, indeed, being loaded into memory as it is.

An instance of a type in the runtime is specific to the *instance* of the assembly loaded - so even if the same DLL file is loaded in a second time, the types are not considered to match.

This is a typical problem when "DLLHell" is extended into the "GACAndDLLHell". "GACONLYHeaven" is a better place ... :).

That the filenames are subtly different (the .DLL extension has a different case) implies that the same DLL is being loaded from two places (that is: the GAC is case-insensitive/always lower case on filenames IIRC).

An abstract class or, preferably, an interface is what you need here.

If you can't make changes to the code base I would, first, make very sure that the DLL exists in only 1 place on the drive (or 0 places on the drive if it is being loaded from the GAC). A copy of the DLL that contains the type: 'CompiledTemplate' in your app /bin folder would be a real culprit ...?

Is this new code or existing code that is now failing for some reason?

Comment: The code is new. There's only one copy of the dll, and it's not in the GAC. The Assembly.Location of the copies of the type that I view in the debugger are identical, and Assembly.Codebase is identical *except* for the casing of the "dll" extension. The real file has a lowercase extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have a WCF net named pipes application that uses a callback (duplex) architecture.

I got this error because my service interface's `[ServiceContract]` was annotated with the wrong callback.